# How to query content of active tab with Chrome Extension Manifest 3?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Using Chrome Manifest 3, how can I write a chrome extension that can query the contents of the active tab? I've looked at the API for [tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/) as well as the [scripting](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/) API, but I can't seem to find the right way to query the DOM contents of the active tab.

When the button in my popup HTML "Save Content" is clicked, I am expecting my function `changeBackgroundColor` to execute, allowing me access to the DOM of the active tab. However, the function never executes and moreover I do not know whether or not I will be able to query the DOM of the active tab while my code executes within `changeBackgroundColor`

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? Here are the relevant files below:

Here is my popup.html:

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <main id="app---KZzQjJcI2kdN0Qnn7X7AgyoO8W6VBwuOPIcyztpKBaU">
      <div class="app__hero-section--KZzQjJcI2kdN0Qnn7X7AgyoO8W6VBwuOPIcyztpKBaUp">
        <button id="save-content--KZzQjJcI2kdN0Qnn7X7AgyoO8W6VBwuOPIcyztpKBaU" class="app__save-content-button--KZzQjJcI2kdN0Qnn7X7AgyoO8W6VBwuOPIcyztpKBaUp">Save content</button>
        <button id="get-images--KZzQjJcI2kdN0Qnn7X7AgyoO8W6VBwuOPIcyztpKBaU" class="app__get-images-button--KZzQjJcI2kdN0Qnn7X7AgyoO8W6VBwuOPIcyztpKBaUp">Get Images</button>
      </div>
      <div class="app_images-hero--KZzQjJcI2kdN0Qnn7X7AgyoO8W6VBwuOPIcyztpKBaUp">
        Select Images To Import
      </div>
      <div class="app_images-section--KZzQjJcI2kdN0Qnn7X7AgyoO8W6VBwuOPIcyztpKBaUp">
      </div>
      <button class="app__import-images-button--KZzQjJcI2kdN0Qnn7X7AgyoO8W6VBwuOPIcyztpKBaUp">Import Images</button>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the JS of the popup:

```
function changeBackgroundColor() {
  console.log('here!!')
}

function findOrCreateContent() {

  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, (tabs) => {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: {tabId: tabs[0].id},
      func: changeBackgroundColor
    })
  });

}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  document.querySelector('#save-content--KZzQjJcI2kdN0Qnn7X7AgyoO8W6VBwuOPIcyztpKBaU').addEventListener('click', findOrCreateContent);
});
```

This is my manifest json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "icons": {
    "16": "thing-icon.png",
    "128": "thing-icon.png"
  },
  "name": "Content Saver",
  "description": "Save content in the cloud",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "action": {
    "default_title": "Content Saver",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "scripting"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Since you load the script tags at the end of body, you need to remove DOMContentLoaded listener and just put its contents at the beginning of the script. Otherwise your code is fine and you can access the tab's contents inside changeBackgroundColor. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu. You can debug your code there and actually see what happens.

Comment: hi @wOxxOm thank you for your comment. I just did what I believe you suggested which was move my click event   `document.querySelector('#save-content--....').addEventListener('click', findOrCreateContent);` to the top of my script file `popup.js` and outside of `DOMContentLoaded` listener. However my function `changeBackgroundColor` is still not executing when I click the button in my popup.html -- `findOrCreateContent` function runs as well as the callback in `chrome.tabs.query`, but `changeBackgroundColor` still does not run. Did I misinterpret your suggestion?

Comment: You probably look in the wrong console. The function runs in the context of the tab so its console.log outputs in the console of the tab, not in the popup.

Comment: oh i see you are correct! My function, `changeBackgroundColor` is indeed running in the active tab. Thank you @wOxxOm !